# Poetry install failing in docker-compose build

Tags: docker, docker-compose, python-poetry

When trying to do `docker-compose build`, I am getting the following error:

```
#0 2.217   • Installing pytest (7.2.0)
#0 2.249 
#0 2.249   RuntimeError
#0 2.249 
#0 2.249   Hash for commons (0.1.0 /app/commons/dist/commons-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl) from archive commons-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl not found in known hashes (was: sha256:c5c93a9a5d1b69db27187040231b429caaf464f743251b7b26d2e4706e9f912e)
#0 2.249 
#0 2.249   at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/executor.py:754 in _validate_archive_hash
#0 2.267       750│         archive_hash: str = "sha256:" + get_file_hash(archive)
#0 2.267       751│         known_hashes = {f["hash"] for f in package.files}
#0 2.267       752│ 
#0 2.267       753│         if archive_hash not in known_hashes:
#0 2.267     → 754│             raise RuntimeError(
#0 2.267       755│                 f"Hash for {package} from archive {archive.name} not found in"
#0 2.267       756│                 f" known hashes (was: {archive_hash})"
#0 2.267       757│             )
#0 2.267       758│ 
#0 2.267 
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c poetry install --with aag-plato]: exit code: 1
```

How do I debug this error? I am new to docker

Explanation and solution to the error and preventive measure in the future to avoid similar errors

Comment: Without your docker-compose.yml file, it's hard to say what exactly the issue is.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on without seeing your `docker-compose.yml` file. Please provide it in your question.

Comment: How did you fix this?

Comment: @Panda I do not remember exactly, but I think I have deleted the lock file and recreated it. We shifted from poetry to requirements.txt as it is much more easier to manage and work with that way. Just need to make sure that your requirements.txt will generate a stable env